# WKWebView doesn't show fonts installed by font provider apps

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, wkwebview, uifontpickerviewcontroller

Since iOS 13, apps can make use of a new `Fonts` entitlement, with a sub option '**Use Installed Fonts**' to use custom fonts installed by special *font provider* apps. These apps make use of the same entitlement, but with sub option '**Install Fonts**'. Examples of such apps are *CreativeCloud* from Adobe and *MyFonts* from MonoType.

Using installed fonts works fine, except with `WKWebView`.

As an example, I use the following code to load some text in a `WKWebView` control, and use a `UIFontPickerViewController` to select a font. After selecting the font, both the font of the webView control and navigation bar are being updated. This works fine with built-in system fonts. But after selecting a custom installed font, only the font of the navigation bar is being updated. This indicates that the app supports the installed custom font, except the `WKWebView` control.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var webView: WKWebView!

    var font = "Avenir Next"

    let html = """
    <style>
    body {
        font-family: 'FONTFAMILY';
        font-size: 40pt;
    }
    </style>

    <body>
    This is a test string to demonstrate the characters of a custom installed font named “<b>FONTFAMILY</b>”. Hopefully it will not be replaced by Times New Roman or some other ugly looking font.
    </body>
    """

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadHTML()
    }

    @IBAction func selectFont(_ sender: AnyObject) {
        let picker = UIFontPickerViewController()
        picker.delegate = self
        present(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    fileprivate func loadHTML() {
        webView.loadHTMLString(html.replacingOccurrences(of: "FONTFAMILY", with: font), baseURL: nil)
        navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: font, size: 24)!]
    }
}

extension ViewController: UIFontPickerViewControllerDelegate {
    func fontPickerViewControllerDidPickFont(_ viewController: UIFontPickerViewController) {
        if let family = viewController.selectedFontDescriptor?.object(forKey: .family) as? String      {
            font = family
            loadHTML()
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**: what must I do get those custom installed fonts working in `WKWebView`?

Most existing questions in stackoverflow about WKWebView and external fonts concerns apps that load custom fonts from their bundle or from an external server. An older technique of installing custom fonts in iOS made use of configuration profiles. This works perfectly with WKWebView, but my question is about the new iOS 13 font installation technique, as explained here: https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/227/.

Answer (score 1):

After contacting Apple via DTS, I received an indirect confirmation that this issue is a bug, because "it may require changes to the OS, tools, or the frameworks you are using". I have filed a feedback and hope for the best.